# Filters on mobile e-commerce

Tags: e-commerce, filter, modal, off-canvas

I’ve been asked to produce a research on **mobile filters**. We do have e-commerces that are adaptive. Any native app is going to be developed over the short term.
I’ve done **benchmarking** and come up with some sort of best practices but also referred to Baymard and Nielsen.
Do you have any other research/resource to share?

We do have **many criteria** and offer **many options** beneath. I would think of an off-canvas in order to handle vertically a great amount of labels and after that a slide effect showing any sub level with the full list of options. Maybe a top-left arrow could help users climb up the information tree. 
Apply/Cancel buttons would be required if **context** is lost, while a simple   realtime approach would be ok if listing is showing on a side.
I’ve also been asked to ponder the use of **modals**.

Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar recently. We ended up going with an overlay because we had to cram a ton of options in the filtering system and our desktop version had the filtering in a permanent sidebar. If you have a desktop version using an off-canvas, you may opt to do the same on mobile to keep it consistent.

[image: Filter]

This is the filter as it is presented on the search page. We hid the actual filter under a button, with an option to specify for relevancy, price, rating etc. The option to view the items in grid or list view is clustered until a toggle.

If you're currently filtering, you can show the tags under the filter itself. This way you don't have to go inside of the filter to see if you're actively filtering already and to which keywords.

[image: Filter detail]

The actual filter itself is an overlay which repeats the tags and shows all possible categories you can filter on. It also gives you the option to search on a main level (like anything involving cars, including parts) or a more narrow option (like a car brand). This is very specific for our use of a filter, so you may not even need to do that.

We also offered an option to filter based on proximity since we sell products that can be picked up or delivered, again may not apply to your situation but you can put it into a filter.

Lastly, anything with a ton of possible filter options had a show more button, so you can order this list either on alphabet or popularity.